# Oracle Linux Gnome Installation Black Screen

Tags: linux, gnome, gui, yum, oracle-linux

I want to install a GUI environment (GNOME) to OEL 7 Server. I ran command below to do this:

```
yum group install Server\ with\ GUI
```

But after than starting the installation I got a transaction error like this:

```
.
.
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service from 
install of gnome-software-3.22.7-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from 
package gnome-packagekit-common-3.14.3-7.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

Edit:
I updated the package and problem has been solved but I have another problem right now. When I started the graphical.target I can see just black screen and a black mouse cursor. There is no another thing.

Note: I changed the topic of this question from "Linux GUI Installation Transaction Error" to "Oracle Linux Gnome Installation Black Screen"